# Generate a excel with data from multiple lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, jquery, excel, xml

we have a requirement , need to generate a excel report from multiple SharePoint lists(SharePoint 2013). can any one help on this what is the better approach to do or any reference URLs available.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an employee asset report in Excel using data from 3 separate lists.

What I do is export each list to a separate tab in an Excel document. I leave the resulting tables attached to the SharePoint data, and save the document to a SharePoint library. That way you can bring it up again and either refresh the data (or define it to refresh automatically on opening). All of that is standard SharePoint/Excel integration.

On a separate tab in Excel, I can reference those tables with pivots or use VB code to read through those tabs to get the information I need. That's standard Excel functionality.

The asset report used a lot of VB code since there was a lot of special formatting. I've also done a time reporting project using pivot tables to slice and dice the information.

This is one of the ways we do customized reporting for those people who are Excel experts (I'm not) but not programmers familiar with javascript/JQuery.